Identifying 1911 Russian Empire town name that looks like "Zyinsta" or "Zejinsta"
On his 1911 immigration card my ancestor from the Russian Empire wrote a town name that looks to my eyes (I'm bad at reading cursive) to be something like "Zyinsta, Russia", but I haven't been able to find any town named anything similar to that. He was a carpenter who was ethnically German but also spoke fluent Polish, reportedly he did not usually speak Russian so I'm not sure how good he was at it. He ended up marrying a Polish woman from the center of modern Poland who had Polish as her first language, who was also ethnically German. To my knowledge he was raised in what is now Zhytomyr, Ukraine. He was Evangelical Lutheran.
On other documents he wrote he was from Swel, Russia (which I took to mean Zviahel, Zhytomyr, Ukraine) but this immigration card is a mystery to me, as far as I could find there is no variant of Zviahel or Zhytomyr that looks anything like "Zynista".
I would like to know what town and region this is if possible.




Are you sure this 1911 document is genuine? The form contains a field "Section and subdivision Act of 1924" which clearly refers to The Immigration Act of 1924 which, quoting Wikipedia, "set quotas on the number of immigrants from Eastern and Southern Europe."

In addition: this form seems to be filled by the officer (Daniel's original handwriting is on the top). Is that possible the town name was rewritten from another handwriting introducing mistakes, e.g. mixing the Polish crossed L (ł) with "t"?

I see no reason to doubt the form's authenticity, it is from the government archives along with the forms for countless other passengers. It may well have been copied over by hand at a later date by an official. While Daniel spoke Polish he was likely educated in German, and he only had a 3rd or 4th grade education. Additionally the Polish spelling system was reformed after this, in the 1930s. I would be unable to recognize ł in cursive.

Daniel petitioned for US citizenship and eventually got it in 1928, so I wonder if the county court had the immigration authorities make a copy of his immigration records (after 1924 during the naturalization process), which they could have done by hand on a then-modern immigration form. That would clear up the discrepancy in the 1924 field versus the 1911 date written on the actual card.
